# Проблема с выводом HTML кода

Tags: html

У меня проблема: подскажите, как на странице сайта вывести `html` код, но при этом чтобы он не исполнялся и был отредактированным, как и на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/.
Спасибо!

Comment: Какими средствами вы хотите это сделать? С помощью JavaScript, простого HTML, либо другими языками программирования?

Comment: <code></code>

Answer (score 0):

Вам понадобится тег code. Ну или можете заменять символы на их варианты по типу такого &#1234.